# How to do batch upsert postgres

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and want to use batch upsert if possible with postgresql not sure it is possible or not(batch upsert) as we can do batch insert/update.

I am using postgres 9.5

Comment: postgres does not have `UPSERT` statement. It offers `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE` for this functionality. so if `codeigniter` allows you to do batch `INSERT` I believe this is it?..